# Understanding AppKey security (without secret)

Tags: java, spring, api, security

I saw many services, mainly map services like GMaps or MapQuest, that requires users registers previously to obtain an `appKey`. Later, on each request the user must attach the `appKey` like `http://server/service?appKey=sdf7dfj34`.

I understand this kind of appKeys are insecure and are mainly usefull to know the useage of your service. Anyone can see your `appKey` and make use on its own app.

I saw other services that, on registration proces, requires you put the domain where you will execute your code. This way they can check if the domain from which the request is made corresponds to the appKey generated for that domain.

My questions are:

- Is this kind of control secure?
- Can I ensure the user is really the one who register.
- If the domain-appKey options is possible, how can implement it? (I'm using Java-Spring).

I must clarify my intention is users can requests data via appKey using JavaScript+AJAX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just include the domain in the appKey? E.g. part of the appKey is hash of the domain (for simplest key you can use MD5 and base64 to encode hash bytes).

Then to validate domain you hash the request's domain and compare it with the appKey.

To clarify:

1. User wants to obtain an appKey for domain "user.domain.com".
2. You hash the "user.domain.com" to SOME_DOMAIN_HASH_TOKEN.
3. The appKey would be SOME_GUID + SOME_DOMAIN_HASH_TOKEN (+ may be something else)
4. User sends the appKey to your server from some domain.
5. You hash the domain from request and compare with hash from the appKey.
6. If both are SOME_DOMAIN_HASH_TOKEN the domain is valid.

Comment: My intention is users can make request via AJAX. Can it be an issue to detect the domain from which requests are made? I mean because code is executed by the browser. Thanks.